# SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier CNN model with one hot encoding

Tags: python, deep-learning, one-hot-encoding

I am losing my mind right now trying to fix this. I have tried adding parentheses after 'relu' and other formats but for some reason, I am not seeing/fixing the issue. Any help would be much appreciated. I am sure it is simple and I am just tired.

Adding parentheses after 'reul'

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten
#create model
model = Sequential()
#add model layers
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation=’relu’, input_shape=(99,4457,4)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation=’relu’))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation=’softmax’))
```

File "", line 6
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation=’relu’, input_shape=(99,4457,4)))
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Answer (score 2):

Use `3,3` instead of `kernel_size=3`.It will solve your problem .

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten
#create model
model = Sequential()
#add model layers
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(99,4457,4)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation=’softmax’))
```

Comment: Omg thank you !  Now I  am recivng this error:                                                                             File "<ipython-input-319-3e1264182432>", line 9
    model.add(Dense(10, activation=’softmax’))
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: Add one layer neuron after Flatten(). model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu')). It should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem, what changed for me was changing the identifier "surrounding" the word relu. This one **' ' - example: 'relu'** , instead of the **high comma ’ ’**. So:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten
#create model
model = Sequential()
#add model layers
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```